# How can I flash a custom firmware on my router carrier?

Tags: networking, router, firmware

I want to know how to flash a firmware to my router because my current router needs a lot of options like QOS.

I searched a lot but the problem is my router is signed to a specific carrier so I don't think that I can flash DD-WRT firmware on my router.

I couldn't find one for it.

Comment: You won't be able to, if your router doesn't even give you a way to flash the firmware, you can't flash the firmware.

Comment: My router provides a way to flash new frimware but the problem is i dont know zhat toflash or even how to flash

Comment: You find custom firmware for the router, the using the web interface, you upload the firmware.  If you can't find the firmware from DD-WRT or OpenWRT it likely doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes thats it i couldnt find the right frimware beacause my router is signed to a specific carrier unlike netgar and linksys and much more .. My router's hardware huawei and the carrier is Orange

Comment: So custom firmware doesn't not exist because the current firmware will only accept signed firmware, there is your answer, to your question

Comment: So i cant flash frimware like dd-wrt?

Comment: You literally just said you can't....you confirmed based on the answers you just provided to my follow up question, that the firmware will not let you upload any firmware that isn't from your ISP;  I have doubts the interface you have access to even has the option to upload firmware; most modem gateways do not which is what you have

Comment: What is the make and model of your router? Only certain routers can be flashed with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices). You might look at Tomato firmware if your router supports it. Usually ISP routers will not support flashing because they are not high quality and you have to purchase a higher quality router yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to be able to find a custom firmware for just about any router.  One way you can do it however is to buy a router that you CAN install a custom firmware on, if it doesn't already have a better firmware, and go into your carrier router and look for "residential gateway" or similar.  Disable that and your carrier router becomes just a plain old modem.  Then plug your other router into port 1 of the now modem and use your router for whatever you need.

If you don't own the router, if your carrier does, then the above is the best way to go about it.  Also, if it is a router/modem that is the only one your carrier supports then the above is also best.  If you own the router/modem then of course you are free to turn it into a brick if you like.